# Cassandra cluster reset the modified value to initial cassandra.yaml configuration value when restart docker container

Tags: docker, cassandra, cluster-computing

I'm running docker container with cassandra image. But running on vm occurs changing bridged-ip. I want to modify cassandra.yaml configuration. I tried modify cassandra.yaml configuration with `docker cp`. I checked the values of cassandra.yaml which I want to modify are modified properly before restart container. But After restart container values that I modified are reset.

OS: CentOS Stream release 9

Docker: Docker version 24.0.6 build ed223bc

Image: Cassandra:4.1.2

I would really appreciate it if you could tell me where I made a mistake.

Comment: Have you commited a new docker image?

Comment: No I didn't. I Known "docker commit" as creating a new image, and what I want is to change the settings in an existing container. Is it impossible to modify the internal files of a container run with the Cassandra official image?